# In React with Redux, why routerReducer is needed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can see some sample projects are using `routerReducers` when call `combineReducers()`, e.g.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

import posts from './posts'
import comments from './comments'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({posts, comments, routing: routerReducer})
```

why it is necessary to add `routerReducer` as an argument of `combineReducers()`?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we want to store router state inside  Redux Store then we have to use 
routerReducer.In simple case we do only

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import counter from './counter'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  counter
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That because redux will store all state in **one** store.

That's **only one store** in an app with redux, so you will need to combine all your reducers together to one, and create the only store from it.

Please see [Principles Of Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) to get details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, react-router-redux helps to track the routing histories. It said ["It can do time travel"](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router)